# R is an integral domain with p in R and p not equal to 0 and if p|ab than p|a or p|b. Prove that p is irreduciable.

Tags: abstract-algebra

So this is what Im thinking:

We know that in order for p to be irreducible it must be prime

Also, since p is defined to have the property if p|ab than either p|a or p|b

But if p has this property than p must be prime

Thus p is irreducible

But I don't really know if this proof would actually hold. I tried proving that p is prime by proving that if p|ab than p|a or p|b by supposed p didnt divide a and then proved p|b. But what about in the case when p isn't prime? As a response to my own question we already know p has this property so if p isn't prime than this property wouldn't hold. But how would I show that?

Any suggestions?

Comment: "We know that in order for $p$ to be irreducible it must be prime." Really?

Answer (score 3):

One should demand that $p$ is not a unit. Then the claim is precisely that every prime is irreducible. Your proof attempts are only reformulations.

The proof is quite easy: Let $p$ be prime. When $p=ab$, then $p|ab$, hence $p|a$ or $p|b$. Since we also have $a|p$ and $b|p$, it follows that $p \sim a$ or $p \sim b$ (associated). Hence $p$ is irreducible.

Answer (score 0):

**A start:** Assume to the contrary  that $p$ is not irreducible, and let $a$ and $b$ be such that $p=ab$ and neither $a$ nor $b$ is a unit.

Comment: A direct argument is (as so often) more easy and short.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\rm\; a,b,p \;$ be elements of a domain $\rm\:Z\:$.

**Definition** $\rm\quad\; a\;$ is a **unit** $\ \ $ if $\rm\ \ a\: |\: 1\qquad\qquad\,\ \  (\:a\ |\ b\,\ :=\,\ a\ \ divides\ \ b\:)$

**Definition** $\quad$ nonunit $\rm\; p\;$ is $\quad\;$ **prime** $\quad\;$ if $\;\;\;\rm p \ \ |\ \ ab \;\;\Rightarrow\;\; p\,|\,a \;\;\; or \;\;\; p\,|\,b$

**Definition** $\quad$ nonunit $\rm\; p\;$ is $\:$ **irreducible** $\,$ if $\;\:\rm p = ab \;\;\Rightarrow\;\; p\,|\,a \;\;\; or \;\;\; p\,|\,b\quad$ (a.k.a.$\:$ **atom**)

**Corollary** $\quad\;$ prime $\ \Rightarrow\ $ irreducible, $ $ since $\ \ \ \, \rm p = ab \;\;\Rightarrow\;\; p\,|\,ab$